# Math formula using a ternary operator causes error

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, el

I am using a ternary operator as part of a mathematical formula.  My intention is to reduce the cost of an item by 1.5% if its condition is "poor."  Below is the formula:

```
<c:out value="${usedEquip.cost * ( 1 - ("poor" == usedEquipItem.condition ? 0.015 : 0) ) }" />
```

The file is a JSP running in Tomcat.  This line of code produces an error which says "equal symbol expected."  I suspect that the problem is something other than a missing equal sign.  Can anyone see what my problem is here?  Is there a better way to do this?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `"poor"` with `'poor'`, or escape the character by doing \"poor\". 
You already have quotation mark in your value (value=""), including another quotation mark will not work in jstl. 
Also you can also replace `==` with `eq`

Comment: Son of a gun!  This is pretty basic and I should have known this.  Thanks for straightening me out.